# Updating the proxy entity using android fails with  "A request is already in progress"

Tags: android, requestfactory

What's a good pattern to use, when I want to 
create the proxy entity -- works

set some properties -- works

send to GAE -- works

if the "save" button is clicked again

```
proxy = requestContext.edit(proxy_returned_from_server_above); // fails with "A request is already in progress"
```

I have spent a few days, trying many options, without any luck.
Is there a sample android app or suggestions? something that used GAE, android and GWT `requestfactory`?

using a "new" `requestContext` as some suggest does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. So i figured it out that you have to build the MyRequestFactory every time before call its method.

```
        //Build this every time
        MyRequestFactory requestFactory = Util.getRequestFactory(mContext,
                MyRequestFactory.class);
        //
        final CustomRequest request = requestFactory
                .customRequest();

        request.queryImages().fire(
                new Receiver<List<ImageProxy>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(ServerFailure error) {
                        String erro = "Failure: "
                                + error.getMessage();
                        Log.e("fail",
                                erro);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(List<ImageProxy> result) {
                        db.importImage(result);
                    }
                });
```